# Getting Facebook chat history to mobile xmpp clients

Tags: facebook, xmpp, chat, history

Is it possible (allowed by FB) to get the chat message history, which is stored at FB? We are developing iOS and Android xmpp chat clients and couldn't find a way how our chat client can display conversation between users, which was stored by FB. To be concrete: First user "A" (using our client) has talked with a second user "B" (using "original" FB chat) and we need to display the communication history of these users (if possible all history, no matter if it happened from our client or if A and B talked directly on FB).
Any help would be highly appreciated!!! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to check these links out (specifically for the read_mailbox function)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/

and/or

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/message/